# Prove that this set (involving fractional part of any rational number) is a partition of the set of rationals.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, integer-partitions

For any rational number $x$, we can writte $x=q+\,n/m$ where $q$ is an integer and $0\le n/m<1$. Call $n/m$ the fractional part of $x$. For each rational $r\in \{x : 0\le x<1\}$ ,let $A_r = \{ x\in \Bbb Q: \text{the fractional part of $x$ is equal to}\; r\}$.

Prove :$\{A_r : 0\le r<1\}$ is partition of $\Bbb Q$

Comment: You asked 5 questions in 1 hour, each time simply copying the text of your homework without adding any personal insight. This flouts the rules of the site. Would you mind changing this modus operandi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: To prove that $\{A_r:r\in\Bbb Q\cap[0,1)\}$ is a partition of $\Bbb Q$, you must show that each $A_r$ is a non-empty set of rational numbers, and that every rational number belongs to exactly one $A_r$. It’s clear from the definition that each $A_r\subseteq\Bbb Q$, and you should have no trouble exhibiting a particular rational number that belongs to $A_r$. That leaves you only two things to show:

1. each rational number belongs to some $A_r$ with $r\in\Bbb Q\cap[0,1)$, and
2. if $r,s\in\Bbb Q\cap[0,1)$, and $r\ne s$, then $A_r\cap A_s=\varnothing$.

The first sentence of your question gives the justification for (1), so really all that’s left is to prove (2). I suggest proving the contrapositive: if $x\in A_r\cap A_s$, then $r=s$.

Comment: thanks so a lot it really helpful

Comment: @megan: You’re welcome.